# Undo/Redo Best Practices with MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, undo-redo

I am working on essentially a drawing editor that allows you to define geometries based on key points on existing geometries. The user is then able to add some information about the thing they just added, such as name, expected size, etc. The API I am using to accomplish it is the awesome [Reversible](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22502/Make-Your-Application-Reversible-to-Support-Undo-a) API, though I hope that the question extends beyond the API that I am using.

There are basically a couple questions that I am seeking a little clarity on:

1) If you are supporting Undo/Redo with an application that supports selection in a Master/Detail manner, should changing the state of a drawing object also cause it to be selected? The example being that an undo operation changed the name of an element, and that change would not be obvious unless the element was selected. Is there considered a standard behavior for something like this?

2) When dealing with certain types of incremental changes (Dragging box, or using a numeric spinner), it seems to be standard form for a set of changes to be grouped into a single user interaction (mouse swipe, or the act of releasing the spinner button), but when dealing with MVVM, I currently only know that the property has changed and not the source of the change. Is there a standard way for these types of interactions to propagate to the view model without completely disintegrating the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt the best approach is to take a look at typical behaviour of OS controls and other applications on the platform in order to be consistent with what users will be familiar with. In particular, consistency with the most commonly-used applications. If you examine how other apps approach a UI issue you can often learn a lot, especially about subtle cases you may not have considered in your own design.

1) Conventionally, undoing tends to select the changed item(s), both to highlight what changed and to move the user's input focus back to the last edit so that they can continue. This works particularly well for content like text because if you undo/redo something you typed, chances are you want to continue editing in the area of the text you've just undone/redone. The main choice for you to make with master/detail is whether to select the master object only, or to select the precise detail that changed.

2) Your undo manager can use some intelligence to conglomerate similar actions into a single undo step. For example, if the user types several characters in a row, it could notice that these actions are all alike and concatenate them into a single undo step. Just how it does this depends on how you are storing and processing the undo, but with a decent object oriented design this should be an easy option to add (i.e. ask undo records themselves if they can be conglomerated so you can easily add new types of undo record in future). Beware though that accumulating too many changes into one step can be intensely irritating, so you may find the lazier implementation of one action = 1 step actually achieves a better UX than trying to be too clever. I'd start with brute force and add conglomeration only if you find you end up with lots of repetitive undo sequences (like 100 single pixel-left movements instead of just one 100-pixel jump)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I suppose I am not completely sure I agree with your answer for #2 because I am not sure an object could truly know if it is allowed to conglomerate or not. The best way I could think to word it is that the user model is a 1:1 mapping between a manipulation on their part and a undo item on the stack. If the user clicks and drags a box, then releases, and then drags again, one would expect to have 2 distinct operations. The problem is that this doesn't map to MVVM well because view models are ideally agnostic of the view, and thus standard forms of user manipulation.

Comment: If you drag an item 5 pixels to the left, then drag it 10 pixels to the left, could that be conglomerated as a single 15-pixel move? So if you add two "move" steps in a row, they can choose to conglomerate themselves - but only if that makes sense in their context of course. If you move then resize, the steps are not compatible, so would remain distinct.

Comment: The problem is that the implementation of move doesn't match the logical action of moving, such that moving right 10, releasing, selecting, moving left 10, releasing, while the user model is 2 distinct actions due to the release/select, the undo redo stack would have 2 "move" actions next to each other, so the naive implementation would try to coalesce those into a move 0. The real problem is that selection is almost never considered an undoable action itself, and thus wouldn't create a barrier between 2 like objects. MVVM hides the steps because it would generally just be a position binding

Comment: In my mind, move left and move right are not equivalent actions, so should not be coalesced. If the moves apply to different objects they cannot be coalesced. But move left and move left of a single object could be coalesced. This is why you allow the "move" undo action to determine whether it can be coalesced with the previous one - coalescing should only occur in a few very specific cases which depend on the precise details of the actions themselves.

Comment: I tested it on a few ubiquitous apps, like word and visio, and you can select an object, go crazy swiping it around, and then deselect it. It records the start and end of the action, but not the swiping. This poses a challenge for MVVM as far as I can tell because I just have something bound to a position trait on my VM, and have no way of knowing what the user interaction was. I need to do some further research on how people overcome this.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're getting at. Generally programs don't record the user interaction, but only the end result. So if you swish an object left and right 5 times during a drag, and drop it 10 pixels to the left of its starting point, the program will usually only record the final result, "move left 10 pixels". In most cases there is no point in recording any intermediate motions of the object due to user indecisiveness, only the "committed" end result. If you want to record every movement you're really trying to record and play back live motion, not implement "undo/redo".

Comment: I suppose what I am getting at is that the view model is what it capturing all of the intermediate steps because it is the real time representation. I don't know of any paradigms for cleanly informing the view model of the start of an interaction without completely breaking the paradigm.